# Minecraft Pocket Edition Multiplayer not working

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought this Minecraft https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe (v0.7.6)
And since then i've been struggling with getting multiplayer to work in any way. My first attempt was to create a server from here: http://www.pocketmine.net/ which not only suffers from bad program design, but also doesn't seem to do anything with my Minecraft on the phone.

I have disabled firewall completely, made sure that computer(server) and client(phone) is on the same network.

At this point i decided to ditch the host a server thing, and we tried doing a regular network play between 2 phones with no success. Nothing appears in the lobby!

Do they have a support section cause i can't seem to find it...

My phone: Sumsung Galaxy Note 3 (my very first smartphone. Not more than a week old)

Other phone: Sumsung Galaxy S3

My comp: Win7...

Another thing I'd mention is that my friend (the SGS3 owner) claims to have been able to play LAN games with other friends. I have not seen this, and there's probably more to it, but if its true then there's probably something wrong with my device. (A default restrictive policy or something...)

Comment: Minecraft PE doesn't play with the computer version, so you won't be able to host a server on the computer and connect to it from the phone, but you ought to be able to play with two phones just fine.

Comment: @Yamikuronue They're talking about PocketMine, which *is* a PE server that runs on PC. And as for playing LAN with another phone, lots of people seem to have problems with that judging by how often this question gets asked.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Oh! Well nevermind then, that sounds awesome. And when I say 'ought to' I mean 'the program claims to support it'.

Comment: @CyberFoxHax Minecraft PE is a game from Mojang AB, [whose support site is here](https://help.mojang.com/).